# TFS 2012 deploy static html

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Our small group has been using TFS 2012 for version control and we would like to start using it to deploy some of our stuff to our test servers (possibly production). The servers, in the case, are Apache. The first project I'm working with is basic, static, html files. These files simply need to be copied to the destination folder (using something like robocopy). It seems like this should be really simple process to setup but I'm  having trouble figuring it out and/or finding information to help me figure it out (maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms). I'm a complete n00b when it comes to deployment using TFS and I'm far from an expert when it comes to anything TFS related.

Can anyone recommend some very basic tutorials on how to create simple build process templates or, can someone provide a basic xaml file which might do the type of deployment I'm looking to create. The default templates that are in TFS seem pretty complicated and very difficult for a n00b to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've used custom build tasks in TFS to Robocopy folders between servers, it sounds like you don't need something that complicated (yet). Assuming you are deploying to a test server that has IIS installed, check out [this](http://chriskadel.com/2013/03/using-tfs-to-build-and-deploy-during-the-build-process-with-ms-deploy/) for a straightforward description of deploying a web site with TFS and Web Deploy.

Comment: Ooops. I forgot to mention. In this application, the servers are Apache Tomcat. I've updated my question to include that info.

Comment: I had a little time to mess with the web deploy within Visual Studio today. I didn't realize it had an option to deploy to a "File System" location. I think I can make this work.

Setting up an FTP server on the servers might make it work better. I can setup web deployment to use FTP using a password that no one else knows.